# Google Plus login - provide user email redirect to browser/Google Plus app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-plus

Is there a way to provide user email to `GPPSignIn` object before calling `[self.signIn authenticate];` so user wouldn't have to enter it in browser/Google Plus app to login in using Google account? I want to pass user email to the login form so the user had only to enter the password. I ask user for email earlier, so in most scenarios I can use it to help him login in fewer steps. `self.signIn.userEmail` is read-only so won't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

user need to enter email and password if its the first time else doesn't have to.

```
- (IBAction)Btn_gogleShare:(id)sender {

            if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
                NSLog(@"share");
                [self GoogleShare];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Login");
                [self GoogleLogin];

            }
     }
```

#pragma mark - Google+ ALL ACTIVITY

```
#pragma mark - Google+ Login

- (void)GoogleLogin{

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email

    // You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step
    signIn.clientID = kClientID;
    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
    //signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ];            // "profile" scope

    // Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
    signIn.delegate = self;

    [signIn authenticate];

    [self showLoadingView:@"Authorizing..."];

}

- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
    //  NSLog(@"%@", signIn.authentication.userEmail);
    [self hideLoadingView];

    [self GoogleShare];
}

#pragma mark - Google+ share

- (void)GoogleShare{

    id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

    // This line will fill out the title, description, and thumbnail from
    // the URL that you are sharing and includes a link to that URL.
    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/restaurant/sf/1234567/"]];

    [shareBuilder open];

}


#pragma mark - Google+ signOut

- (void)signOut {
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know if I can pass the user email to the login form so the user had only to enter the password. I wanted to reduce the number of steps that user has to make.

Comment: user email is different for each user so how would it be helpfull. i have found that if user has already login in browser or apps of that cell phone then it will give you option to use it or add next

Comment: I ask user for his email before, so in most scenarios I can use it.

Comment: Your code is useful but it is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry that i couldnot provide what you want

Comment: No worries :) Thanks for your effort